allauth twitch oauth 2.0 and Login
Is it possible to get the twitch access_token using the allauth library, and, at the same time, log in?
If so, how do you do it? And, if so there was the access_token, it will be automatically saved in the socialaccount_socialtoken table
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'twitch': {
        'APP': {
            'client_id': '',
            'secret': '',
            'key': ''
        },
        'SCOPE': {
            'user:read:chat',
            'user:read:follows',
            'bits:read',
            'user:read:subscriptions',
            'moderation:read',
            'moderator:read:chatters',
            'moderator:read:followers',
            'moderator:read:blocked_terms',
            'channel:read:redemptions',
            'channel:read:vips',
            'channel:read:subscriptions',
            'moderator:manage:banned_users',
            'moderator:manage:blocked_terms',
            'moderator:manage:chat_messages',
            'channel:manage:broadcast',
            'channel:manage:polls',
            'channel:manage:vips',
            'channel:manage:redemptions',
            'clips:edit',
            'channel:edit:commercial',
        },
        'LOGIN_CALLBACK_URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/twitch/login/callback/',
        'AUTH_PARAMS': { 'response_type': 'code' },
        # 'AUTH_PARAMS': { 'response_type': 'token' },

    },
}

